# Can I print apache environment variable in error log?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

I want to print mod_security anomaly score to apache error log.
I use `setenv` to set enviroment variable, and `%{name}e` syntax to print it in log.

Modsecurity config:

`SecAction "id:90100,phase:5,pass, nolog, setenv:ModSecAnomalyScoreIn=%{tx.anomaly_score}, setenv:ModSecAnomalyScoreOut=%{TX.outbound_anomaly_score}"`

Apache config:

`ErrorLogFormat "[...] [anomaly_score_in: %-{ModSecAnomalyScoreIn}e, anomaly_score_out: %-{ModSecAnomalyScoreOut}e ]"`

But the output is empty:
`[...] [anomaly_score_in: -, anomaly_score_out: - ]`

If I add `SecAction "id:9990101,phase:5,pass, log, msg:'in: %{env.anomaly_score}, out: %{env.ModSecAnomalyScoreOut}'`, scores are printed, but in new log line.

Where did I go wrong?

Does the `%{name}e` in [ErrorLogFormat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ErrorLogFormat) is equal to `%{VARNAME}e` in [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)?

Comment: Read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats, and perhaps some more of the `mod_log_config` documentation

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a dash between the `%` and the `{` in the first non-working example?

Also the [Modsecurity reference manual](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#Logging_in_Apache_via_mod_log_config) says you should use `%{modsecurity_variable_name}M` instead of `%{modsecurity_variable_name}e`.

So I believe your final config should be:

```
ErrorLogFormat "[...] [anomaly_score_in: %{ModSecAnomalyScoreIn}M, anomaly_score_out: %{ModSecAnomalyScoreOut}M ]"
```

Note also that custom ErrorLogFormats only work with ModSecurity 2.9.1 or above: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/pull/840

Comment: Hi! Output: `[anomaly_score_in: [client ...] ModSecurity: Warning. detected SQLi using libinjection with fingerprint...` . It seems that `%{something}M` works only in `LogFormat`, not in `ErrorLogFormat`.

Comment: Probably, apache handles this - `ErrorLogFormat "[...] [anomaly_score_in: %{ModSecAnomalyScoreIn}M` like this `ErrorLogFormat "[...] [anomaly_score_in: %M`, and prints "actual log message".